# How to reduce an user data type notation? (typedef?)

Tags: c++, syntax

I use [ttmath](http://www.ttmath.org/) library for `C++` (big nums).
And I use 2D arrays (matrices).
For example:

```
#define FOR(i,a,b) for(int (i)=(a); i<(b) ; ++(i))
#define Big ttmath::Big<2, 2>
vector < vector < Big > > A(n);
FOR(i, 0, n) 
   A[i].resize(n);
```

Where A -- a square matrix NxN.
But I want type just:

```
Matrix A(n);
FOR(i, 0, n) 
   A[i].resize(n)
```

I tried to use typedef:

```
typedef vector < vector < Big > > Matrix;
```

But it doesn't compile.

MS VS 2013:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
```

(In line with typedef).

Whole "[project](http://pastebin.com/KtLwjEua)". :)

Comment: What's the error message? Have you used `using namespace std;` before?

Comment: @cad error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
MS VS 2013.

Yes, I have this line `using namespace std;` in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the recursive macro `Big` and use a `typedef` instead, something like:

```
typedef ttmath::Big<2, 2> Big_type;
typedef std::vector<std::vector<Big_type> > Matrix_type;
Marix_type A(n);
FOR(i, 0, n) 
    A[i].resize(n)
```

Comment: Still have the same problem.
`error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'ttmath::Big<2,2>'`
Of course, I have commented that before `#define Big ttmath::Big<2, 2>`.

Comment: I think all right, becouse all works fine without `typedef`.

Comment: Ahah, Paul, you have made mistake in answer and I just copied it! You typed "typdef", without "e". :))

Comment: Now it works fine. Thx. :) And, if it possible, can you explain a little bit more about "recursive macro Big"? What happend in my case?

Comment: Well spotted. Still getting used to using a tablet:( Macros can't be recursive but it's confusing if its name appears in the replacement text. They're simply best avoided since language features like `typedef` hold onto information rather than mindlessly replace text.